# Get Image upload file type in Java

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2

After uploading a file it gets stored as a .tmp file in a temp directory.

How can one get the actual file type of the file that was uploaded? I need to know if it's a bmp, jpeg, png, etc. from server side.

**Note:** I'm also using Struts 2 version 2.1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On JSP if you have

```
<s:form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

  <s:file name="userFile" label="File" />

  <s:submit />

</s:form>
```

in your ActionClass you need to add

```
public void setUserFileContentType(String userImageContentType) {
    this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
}
public void setUserFileFileName(String userImageFileName) {
    this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
}
```

and then you would have access to the fileName and contentType of uploaded file

Answer (score 1):

Try to touch the mime type of it

```
File f = new File("temp.tmp");
System.out.println("Mime Type of " + f.getName() + " is " + new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
```

the output should be something like: `image/gif` or `image/png` or `image/jpg` etc.

Answer (score 1):

apart from Truong Ha's answer (MimetypesFileTypeMap needs activation.jar), there are some more other ways as well:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

cheers,